# Why is this Unity unit test not setting up correctly?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

I've just started learning about unit testing in Unity, and unit testing in general and have been stuck on writing my first test for my mobile game. I'm following vairous tutorail sites and youtube videos. I think I'm not setting things up correctly, or more likely, haven't understood something fundamental about unit testing.

I'm trying to test the opening scene Start function, which sets up the default values in the Sart Menu UI components.

```
public class StartSceneScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_InputField playerNameInput1, playerNameInput2;
    public TMP_Text warningText;
    public Slider blueShipCountSlider, redShipCountSlider;
    public TMP_Text blueShipCountText, redShipCountText;

    public void Start()
    {
        playerNameInput1.text = "Blue Team";
        playerNameInput2.text = "Red Team";
        warningText.text = "";
        blueShipCountSlider.value = 1;
        redShipCountSlider.value = 1;
        ShowSliderValue();
    }

    public void ShowSliderValue()
    {
        GlobalVariables.blueShipsCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(blueShipCountSlider.value);
        GlobalVariables.redShipsCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(redShipCountSlider.value);
        blueShipCountText.text = GlobalVariables.blueShipsCount.ToString();
        redShipCountText.text = GlobalVariables.redShipsCount.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is the test code. I've tried it both as an Editor test and a Play Mode test, both gave the same error.

```
using System.Collections;
using NUnit.Framework;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.TestTools;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Playtests_StartScene
{

    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator Start_InitializesUIElements()
    {
        // Create a new GameObject with the StartSceneScript component attached
        GameObject startSceneObject = new GameObject();
        var startSceneScript = startSceneObject.AddComponent<StartSceneScript>();

        // Set up the necessary UI components
        startSceneScript.playerNameInput1 = startSceneObject.AddComponent<TMP_InputField>();
        startSceneScript.playerNameInput2 = startSceneObject.AddComponent<TMP_InputField>();
        startSceneScript.warningText = startSceneObject.AddComponent<TMP_Text>();
        startSceneScript.blueShipCountSlider = startSceneObject.AddComponent<Slider>();
        startSceneScript.redShipCountSlider = startSceneObject.AddComponent<Slider>();
        startSceneScript.blueShipCountText = startSceneObject.AddComponent<TMP_Text>();
        startSceneScript.redShipCountText = startSceneObject.AddComponent<TMP_Text>();

        // Call the Start() method of the StartSceneScript component
        startSceneScript.Start();

        // Check that the UI elements have been initialized with the correct values
        Assert.AreEqual("Blue Team", startSceneScript.playerNameInput1.text);
        Assert.AreEqual("Red Team", startSceneScript.playerNameInput2.text);
        Assert.AreEqual("", startSceneScript.warningText.text);
        Assert.AreEqual(GlobalVariables.blueShipsCount, Mathf.RoundToInt(startSceneScript.blueShipCountSlider.value));
        Assert.AreEqual(GlobalVariables.redShipsCount, Mathf.RoundToInt(startSceneScript.redShipCountSlider.value));
        Assert.AreEqual(GlobalVariables.blueShipsCount.ToString(), startSceneScript.blueShipCountText.text);
        Assert.AreEqual(GlobalVariables.redShipsCount.ToString(), startSceneScript.redShipCountText.text);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

The test fails due to the following error:
`System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I used debugging while running the test and traced the error to the second line of the Start function:
`playerNameInput2.text = "Red Team";`

It's occuring because `playerNameInput2` is null. Also, all other components after the first input field are showing null, too. This stumped me because the first `playerNameInput1` is showing as set to a new `TMP_InputField` and it's text is setting to "Blue Team", so I guess the set up portion of the test is running, but giving up after creating the the first input field, but can't figure out why.

Here is a shot of the inspector showing everything on the script object, and the scene hierarchy too. It's basically a UI starting screen.

[Inspector Picture Link](https://www.shonansoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Inspector1.jpg)

[Scene Hierarchy Link](https://www.shonansoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/inspector.jpg)

Also, could you tell me if this particular test would be best done in Editor or play mode?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: just as a note, you really shouldn't be calling start direcltly, its a unity event funciton, let unity call it. You can cause this to happen by `yield return null`ing which will progress the frame, causing start to be called

Comment: Show us a picture of the Inspector with all options expanded on the object containing the StartSceneScript component while in Edit Mode.

Comment: I added an image of the inspector. For some reason it wouldn't let me imbed it. But the link should work.
Would this particular test be better as an Editor test, or a play mode test?